# Part-of-Speech (POS) vs Syntactic Dependency Parsing

Tags: nlp, text-mining, linguistics

I am using SpaCy for text analysis but I cannot understand the difference between Part-of-Speech (POS) and Syntactic Dependency Parsing. Both label the words in a sentence based on their role. But how exactly they are different?

Answer (score 8):

We use Part-of-Speech tagging to label tokens in a sentence with their grammatical word categories as part-of-speech tags. Yet, they do not have any grammatical relations between them.

In order to generate the grammatical relations between the tokens, we use linguistic parsers and syntactic dependency parsing is one of them. Via dependency parsing, we create a tree or a graph data structure of a sentence conveying its tokens' grammatical relations. Parsers generally tokenize, tags with POS the sentence for you and then parse. Therefore, we can say parsing a sentence is a further step.

Here in Berkeley University's demo, you can give it a try to produce a sentence's syntax tree parse and dependency parse trees : http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html

Hope this helps.

Cheers